# Padding in menu bad browsers optimalization Chrome | Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have problem with possition my hover effect in menu. In the Firefox its all right but in chrome is problem that hover effect is UP.

Firefox: (Here is all right)

http://pasteboard.co/1ami0qrP.png

Chrome: (here is problem)

http://pasteboard.co/1amxtlU8.png

Live: gavrilo.iwgaming.eu

I have too problem with text in the firefox is bigger maybe bolder as in chrome ...

Thanks for support ...

Comment: Just a note (best practice)...you must set your style.css before normalize.css

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue is that in chrome the 'home' image in the nav bar is slightly taller than the rest of the menu items. Try setting `height` or `line-height` to a fixed value for this image, and you should then see firefox and chrome match up.

Answer (score 0):

change padding to this in #main_menu Div, may be it will help

Style.css line no. 61

```css
#main_menu ul li a div{

  padding:24px 24px 25px;
}
```